# Some constructions with the adjective INTRUSIVE

Tags: construction

Are these construction correct?

> He was **intrusive in his desire** to be friends with Jack.
>
> She was **intrusive in asking** the questions about Kim and
> Toby's wedding.

I just wanted to translate some sentences into English using these constructions. But I am no sure of they work.

be intrusive in one's desire to do something

be intrusive in doing something

Comment: Can you edit to tell us your doubts here so people can help you better?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of **intrusive in** is fine.

In the second sentence we would often leave out "the".  In certain contexts you could even leave out "the questions" as "to ask about" **implies** questions.

Each of the following is valid but each has a slightly different meaning:

...in asking about...
...in asking questions about...
...in asking the questions about...
...in asking **those** questions about...